# Connect to Google Play Games Services Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to connect to Google Play Games, but there is an error. Every time, the error `unsuccessful sign in` appears.

In my `build.gradle (Module: app)` I have this code:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

At the end of my manifest, I have:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

When I sign in using the `MainActivity.java`,  I call this method in `onResume`:

```
private void signInSilently() {
    context = getApplicationContext();
    signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.oauth_client_id))
    .build();
    GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
    if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(signedInAccount, signInOptions.getScopeArray())) {
        account = signedInAccount;
    } else {
        client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
        client
            .silentSignIn()
            .addOnCompleteListener(
                    this,
                    new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                account = task.getResult();
                            } else {
                                Log.d("George", "onComplete: unsuccessful sign in");
                                //signInLoudly();
                            }
                        }
                        });
    }
}
void signInLoudly(){
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

If I uncomment the `signInLoudly();` method, it just goes round in an infinite loop.

Please, advise. Any help will be greatly appreciated, and if you need any more information, please, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the game was already connected to Google APIs, so I created a new game in Google Play Games that worked. I hope this helps someone with a similar issue.